# want to create two column in first row and one column in 2nd row which will merge two column in htnl css

Tags: html, css

I want to create two columns in the first row, those columns taking 70% and 30% of the space; and in the second row one column. But When I add text and image then it's creating issues and the position of the content is not in the expected place:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("1.JPG");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.div1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.div2 {}

.div3 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div div1">Hi!
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?> Welcome to HMIS</div>
  <div class="div div2">hhhhh</div>
  <div class="div div3">
    <a href="bill.php" class="logo me-auto"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" width="100" height="60"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have left some PHP in your HTML.

Comment: yes i do but i dont think so its have some to do wth styling and positioning

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.div {
  flex: 1;
}

.div3 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

I would suggest you read a bit more about the CSS property FLEXBOX as well as GRID, because that could be even a more neat solution.

Comment: i tried what ever u siggested but now shoing div3 content (which is image) right under signout button at right corner

Comment: Maybe you can update your code a bit more than it would be easier to help. Right now I just don't see what you see.